# Как сделать мигающее окно

Tags: qt, многопоточность

Делаю сейчас программу, в которой второе окно должно мигать морзянкой сменяя черный фон белым. Я уже и через таймер попробовал в самом коде окна и в отдельный поток выкладывал.
Сейчас у меня такой вариант(тестовый) и он не работает. Появляется белое окно, потом проходит время равное сумме всех интервалов таймера и потом окно становится черным, хотя задумка теста - окно должно мигать несколько раз с интервалом, заданным в таймере

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
        this->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::white));
        this->show();
        m_timer->start(2000);
}
```

коннект для приема сигнала от таймера

`QObject::connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(BlackWindow()));`

и сам слот

```
void morzewindow::BlackWindow()
{
    this->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::black));
    this->show();
    m_timer->stop();
}
```

Может у кого-то была подобная задача реализованная средствами Qt? помогите. Мне как новичку уже ни одной идеи в голову не приходит. Все что знал, о чем подозревал, все перепробовал.

UPDATE:

запуск потока и функции в нем:

```
MorzeBlinkTimer.moveToThread(&MorzeBlinkThread);
    QObject::connect(&MorzeBlinkTimer, SIGNAL(latency(bool)), SLOT(Blink(bool)));
    MorzeBlinkThread.start();
    MorzeBlinkTimer.startBlink(etalon2.GetReadyCodeMorzeForBlink());
```

функцию запускаю вручную, потому что она принимает указатель на массив с морзянкой.

//слот для смены цвета окна морзянки черный/белый

```
void morzewindow::Blink(bool BlackWhite)
{
    if(BlackWhite)
    {
        this->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::white));
        this->show();
    }
    else
    {
        this->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::black));
        this->show();
    }
}
```

и сама функция потока, которая вводит задержку(фрагмент):

```
void startBlink(int* morze)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        switch(morze[i])
        {
        case 0:
            emit latency(true);
            QThread::msleep(iDot);
            emit latency(false);
            QThread::msleep(iPauseSymbol);
            break;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно, пока все функции не отработают и не "встанут" в ожидании событий в графическом интерфейсе - он не обновится.

Делать надо отдельным потоком, но там есть тонкости, тоже долго получалось как у вас - что не реагировало окно ни на что, пока не отработают все события.

Вот рабочий пример обновления графического интерфейса в отдельном потоке.

В основной функции у вас должно быть примерено так:

```
    //Starting process in the new thread    
    Worker * pWorker = new Worker;
        QThread * pThread = new QThread();  
    pWorker->moveToThread(pThread);
        connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), pWorker, SLOT(slotDummyUpdatingRequest()));     
// сигнал старта потока соединяем с функцией имеющей задержки
        connect(pWorker, SIGNAL(sigDummyNextRequestStage()), this, SLOT(slotStageRequestPrint())); 
// сигнал от объекта осуществляющего задержки на обновление окна соединяем со слотом обновления окна текущего оъекта    
        pThread->start();
```

И сам слот обновления графики, срабатывающий асинхронно:

```
void UpdatingRequestState::slotStageRequestPrint() {
    //здесь идет установка внешнего вида элементов, в моем случае используется QML
    QObject * pList = m_pQmlObject->findChild<QObject*>("requestList");
    m_strListView.append(tr("requesting info..."));
    pList->setProperty("model", m_strListView);
}
```

Ну и собственно функция, выполняемая в отдельном потоке, по сигналам которой интерфейс обновляется

```
void Worker::slotDummyUpdatingRequest() {
    //dummy imitation of the work
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        QThread::msleep(500); // задержка
        emit sigDummyNextRequestStage();
        qDebug() << "Updating Request...";
    }
}
```

Comment: qDebug пишет что все ок. и тайминги правильные и морзянку отрабатывает как следует, но теперь не открывается ни само окно морзянки, которое должно мигать, ни окно, в котором должны будут вводить коды. Точнее оно показывается, но не успевает даже распахнуться на весь экран и просто висит. Смотрите UPDATE вопроса. Не могу понять что не так.

Comment: qDebug  не показатель, т.к. даже когда окно и поток висят, он будет бодро рапортовать что дошел до нужного места :) на каникулах деталей не вспомню, но тоже был затык на этом месте - qDebug вводил в заблуждение. В вашем коде неверно то, что вы запускаете поток, а потом процесс (пусть он и перемещен ранее в поток) Вам надо именно сигнал старта потока соединить с исполняемой функцией, а не запускать их последовательно - это очень важный пункт!

Comment: То есть придется поломать голову как передать морзянку в функцию потока при том что будет именно автостарт по сигналу. Ок, попробую.

Comment: Нет, у вас будет функция отработки морзянки которая шлет сигналы по таймеру, и функция обновления окна.  Далее сигнал старта потока вы соединяете с функцией морзянки (предварительно перемещенной в этот поток) А потом сигнал из морзянки - к функции обновления окна. D моем ответе этот пример полностью разобран, и так же установлена задержка (только у вас она таймером а не sleep)

Comment: добавила комментарии в ответ, чтоб было понятней

Comment: Я ж в UPDATE описал нынешний вариант. Там нет таймера. А функция потока принимает аргумент, потому и не запускается по сигналу от стартовавшего потока.

Comment: В апдейте вашем вижу morseblinktimer.start похоже на таймер или наследника :)

Comment: Нет. Это функция потока. А называется так потому что она задает тайминги задержки. ) Ну мне так показалось лучше )))

Comment: Сделал вариант функции потока, в котором код морзянки принимается уже внутри функции, после запуска. И сделал коннект по сигналу от запущенного потока "started". Все получилось. Спасибо Вам огромное. Счастья в Новом году и во всех последующих!

Answer (score 0):

Реализовано с использованием стандартных потоков (нет необходимости создавать отдельные классы, просто выполняем функцию в отдельном потоке, не прерывая выполнение `GUI`-потока):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void blinkBackground(QWidget* w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        // 1 секунду показываем красный цвет.
        w->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        // 0.5 секунды показываем желтый цвет.
        w->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    w.show();

    std::thread t(blinkBackground, &w);
    t.detach();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Похожий функционал, но используя QT Threads, можно также реализовать через [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html), например:

```
void blinkBackgroundQt(QWidget* w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        w->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
        QThread::msleep(1000);
        w->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;");
        QThread::msleep(500);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    QtConcurrent::run(blinkBackgroundQt, &w);
    ...
}
```

И третий способ с использованием `QThread` и отдельного класса был уже описан в другом ответе.

Comment: Попробовал я такой вариант, но на этапе исполнения выдает ошибку, что поток пытается изменить ресурс, который ему не принадлежит. Оригинал текста, к сожалению не приведу. Программа сделана по версии с отдельной функцией и сигнал/слотом, смотрите UPDATE вопроса.